# Random Result Pagination

Tags: php, html

I currently have a listing of data that has a randomly generated order listing. Right now there is no pagination, so it is easy for me to generate a randomly ordered list. As my list of data grows, it gets slower because of all the data, so the obvious solution is pagination. The issue that I have with pagination is that I cannot randomly generate the order every time the page loads, so my manager and I have come to the conclusion that a list will have to be pre-generated ahead of time and will be re-generated every x amount of time. Now the issue is how do we store this generated list? There are four options that we've come up with:

1. Session (takes up ram on the server)
2. Cookies (more data is transmitted. Think about thousands of integer values transmitted to the user)
3. Flat File (Implementation might take a bit of time. Not an extreme amount, but a little longer than the rest)
4. database (a cron job will run ever x amount of time and do a mass update on all records. Our worry is that if there is too much data, it might slow down the system if people are hitting the server during an update.)

If there are any other solutions which seem better than pre-generated time-based lists, I'd love to hear about them.

Thanks.

UPDATE: An answer that I really liked, but was deleted for some reason, was that someone mentioned the use of a SEED, then I can store the seed instead of a list of ids, which would cut-down my data storage and simplify everything. I just tested the solution, and it works almost flawlessly. The only problem is that when I use LIMIT, everything will screw up. Does anyone have an suggestions to that? I don't want to have to generate all the data every time, I just want to use LIMIT  * , . If I use this with a seed though, the numbers always reset, as it should.

Hopefully that made sense. It made more sense as I was thinking about it than how it turned out typed.

Comment: Are you sure you need pagination because all the data is slow, or is your current retrieval in random order slow? (ORDER BY RAND() can be a performance killer in MySQL for instance, but easily avoided by just randomzing with generating script instead of the database). If everything in one page is still more desirable then pagination optimizing that might be better then storing pregenerated sequences.

Comment: We are using RAND(), but even if it was efficient, the client still wants to use pagination because it makes it easier to browse through thousands of results.

Comment: i have a similar problem with slowness.  The reason is because each user profile that comes back has a profile image.  I'd prefer to paginate the results.

Comment: My comment is more usability than development, but may solve your issue. If the records you bring back are random, why bother to pageinate? Just pull a few back with the LIMIT clause, and then have a button on the page that allows you to "reshuffle" or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: I agree with @Chris Sobolewski, in the event that any given 'page' of data can contain, potentially, some results from previous/other pages. Is that the case?

Comment: The issue with that is that if they keep going to the next page, there is a high change that they will see the same peice of data across every page, unless I miunderstood your comment.

Comment: I think you understood. So while the order of the-data-as-a-whole is random, the data shown on each page should *not* repeat any previously seen results, correct?

Comment: Exactly. this is why I muse store the IDs which makes it complicated.

Comment: Using a random seed is okay, but you won't be able to do a new LIMIT query on each page, because it will still be getting "new" random information. You will have to choose some method of "remembering" the entire list, as generated, and spreading it across every page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mysql RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) accepts a seed as an optional argument. Using a seed, it will return the same randomized result set each time.

What you could do is generate a random seed in PHP on the first page request and pass it along to each page using a query string.

*Edit: Sorry, I didn't realize the solution was posted already but was deleted.*

Comment: Yup, but the issue with this solution, which I love, is that I can't limit a static number of results, so as the user goes down the pages, poor efficiency starts to kick in. An example is if I do SELECT RAND() FROM my_table LIMIT 1, 5, I will get the same results as SELECT RAND() FROM my_table LIMIT 6, 5, which would be quite random.

Comment: Not sure, seems to be working when I tested it. Are you saying the queries work fine, but are not efficient?

Comment: What I meant was that I was having issues with select sections using the LIMIT. But I think I've come to a solution at this point. My solution is using the id and a seed to generate a unique randomly calculated number. This will allow me to pick from the middle. I will do more testing, and if this works, this random seed will be the solution.

Comment: I could be missing something very obvious here, but is this not the desired result? http://i.imgur.com/5qDSA.png

Comment: yup, that is the exact required result. Unfortunately according to geocar (poster below), my MySQL might have a bug. I don't like updating live servers unless I have to, so unfortunately I'll have to use this workaround for now until I can find a good enough excuse to update the MySQL servers.

Answer (score 0):

Use #4, possibly only storing the IDs of the data to retrieve, in the order they should be retrieved.

Better than that, if possible (since this is similar to a scaling issue) is to pre-generate each page's data. For example, if it's only viewed through a browser, just go ahead and  pre-generate x-number of static pages HTML (or just the table/list portion).

I know that this probably sounds ridiculous without further explanation, but think about one of these options.

Also, if the server is taking that hard of a hit during generation of the results, it needs to be separated from the web server, and possibly the report/generation run on a clone/replicated slave of the original database.

Comment: I like to lean more towards #4 as well because if we use flat-files, we will take the same performance hit as a cron job, but the flat-file guarantees that every time the pre-generated list is generated, a user will feel that performance hit, whereas a cron job will do it in the background, and for a user to feel that performance hit, they'd have to enter the site at that exact moment that database is being updated.

Comment: I'm not sure how often you have to "update" the generated listing, but is it entirely not an option to have it generated from a replicated/slave database of some sort, so that the "real" database takes no hit at all, and therefore the users *never* notice? Is the bottleneck in CPU/Random-Ordering, or elsewhere? Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect. This way you can still use the `RAND()`-trick, but OFFSET won't mess you up.

```
select * from (select * from items order by rand(3) asc) as b limit 5 offset @x;
```

Alternate hint: Upgrade your MySQL. This was an old bug.

---

Example:

```
mysql> select * from (select id from items order by rand(3) asc) as b limit 5 offset 1;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 24621 | 
| 25214 | 
| 27119 | 
| 24672 | 
| 25585 | 
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from (select id from items order by rand(3) asc) as b limit 5 offset 2;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 25214 | 
| 27119 | 
| 24672 | 
| 25585 | 
| 27718 | 
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from (select id from items order by rand(3) asc) as b limit 5 offset 3;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 27119 | 
| 24672 | 
| 25585 | 
| 27718 | 
| 25457 | 
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from (select id from items order by rand(3) asc) as b limit 5 offset 4;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 24672 | 
| 25585 | 
| 27718 | 
| 25457 | 
| 27112 | 
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from (select id from items order by rand(3) asc) as b limit 5 offset 5;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 25585 | 
| 27718 | 
| 25457 | 
| 27112 | 
| 24779 | 
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: RAND() seems to ignore the offset, which makes sense, because we are offsetting x number of rows, so no matter what the first generated row will be the first one because that's when the generate function is called.

Comment: JohnathanKong: I just posted an example to the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Random file, watch this class of caching taked from opencart:

```
<?php
final class Cache {
  private $expire = 3600; 
  public function __construct() {
    $files = glob(DIR_CACHE . 'cache.*');
    if ($files) {
      foreach ($files as $file) {
        $time = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1);
        if ($time < time()) { unlink($file); }
      }
    }
  }

  public function get($key) {
    $files = glob(DIR_CACHE . 'cache.' . $key . '.*');
    if ($files) {
      foreach ($files as $file) {
        $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
        $cache = fread($handle, filesize($file));
        fclose($handle);
        return unserialize($cache);
      }
    }
  }

  public function set($key, $value) {
    $this->delete($key);
    $file = DIR_CACHE . 'cache.' . $key . '.' . (time() + $this->expire);
    $handle = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, serialize($value));
    fclose($handle);
  }

  public function delete($key) {
    $files = glob(DIR_CACHE . 'cache.' . $key . '.*');
    if ($files) {
      foreach ($files as $file) {
        unlink($file);
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

is really simple to use and it works so well, you use the random query and save your data into the file, I post an example.

```
$cache = new cache();
$data = $cache->get('my_query_key');
if (!$data) {
  // I do my query and I put it into an array (because I can use shuffle :P)
  $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM items');
  $data = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $data[] = $row; }
  $cache->set('my_query_key', $data);
}
shuffle($data);
```

The only things that there is a problem when saving more than 100kb of a file, but as rumor, I use it and works very well never get me no problem. Ah.. in this case isn't needed to use RAND() on query. :P

I have write this post without checking sintax, be ware ^^

Answer (score 0):

using seed is thebest solution as said above...

by using the following logic you can 'mess-up' your data for each seperate visitor (using his/her IP) as well as keep your pagination results for a good amount of navifation time...

```
//generate individual seed...
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hour=date("H");
$day=date("j");
$month=date("n");
$ip=str_replace(".","",$ip);
$seed=($ip+$hour+$day+$month);
//query 
$query="SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND($seed) LIMIT $amount OFFSET $offset";
```

pros: fast and easy, no extra load, no cron needed, unique randomness per visitor.

cons: data re-messed if hour (morelike), day or month change during navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working solution based on Kevin's answer:

```
public function galleries(){
   if (!Input::has('page')){                    //it means we are on the first page
      $seed = rand(1, 10);                  //generate a random number between 1 and 10
      Session::put('seed', $seed);          //then pass it to session named 'seed'
   }else{
      if (Input::get('page') == 1){             //this also indicate the first page, because page = 1
         $seed = rand(1, 10);
         Session::put('seed', $seed);
      }
   }

   $orgs = Organization::orderByRaw("RAND(".Session::get('seed').")")->paginate(4); //put the seed value to RAND(), this way, the second page will generate random row with same seed as the first page
   return redirect('galleries')->with('orgs', $orgs);
}
```

}

Cheers.

*Edit : this is a laravel project based, but you get the idea.,*